# React debounce search Cannot access 'updateSearchQuery' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, search, debouncing

I'm trying to implement debounced search to my React app. This is my current code for handling search:

```
const debouncedSearch = debounce(updateSearchQuery, 500);

const handleSearchInputChange = (searchText) => {
    debouncedSearch(searchText);
}

const updateSearchQuery = (searchText) => {
    setSearchQuery(searchText);
}
```

`handleSearchInputChange` is called like this:

```
onSearchChange: (searchText) => {handleSearchInputChange(searchText)
```

This is not working though as I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'updateSearchQuery' before initialization
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue?

Comment: That means you need to move up `updateSearchQuery` definition in your code, technically before using it. Ideally it should be defined before the line `const debouncedSearch = debounce(updateSearchQuery, 500);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of `updateSearchQuery` above where it is referenced:

```
const updateSearchQuery = (searchText) => {
    setSearchQuery(searchText);
}

const debouncedSearch = debounce(updateSearchQuery, 500);

const handleSearchInputChange = (searchText) => {
    debouncedSearch(searchText);
}
```